# Can you bypass docker login when using AWS CDK to upload image to ECR?

Tags: docker, aws-cdk

I am using a CDK code example (I don't believe it's relevant to my question but here is the link: https://github.com/TysonWorks/cdk-examples/tree/master/ecs-go-api) which attempts to upload a docker image to the AWS ECR, however the 'CDK Deploy' command fails with the following error message:
[image]

After much research and testing with the Docker CLI itself, I discovered this happens when the AWS Password used by Docker to login to the ECR is too long for the operating system's Credential Manager (Windows 10 in my case).

This seems to be a known issue and one workaround is to use a Credential Helper (see: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper and read: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/authenticating-amazon-ecr-repositories-for-docker-cli-with-credential-helper/).

This approach allows one to use the 'docker push' command without 'docker login' and this works fine for me as I could use the Docker CLI to push the image to the AWS ECR, HOWEVER the AWS CDK Deploy process uses the 'docker login' approach and so I have the error once again...

Is there a way to change the AWS CDK to use 'docker push' without 'docker login'?

Comment: I have the same problem trying to publish an image to ECR using CDK. Did you find any solution or work around?

Comment: Sorry @marianog I didn't find a direct solution to this issue. (I resorted to using AWS Chalice which does a lot of the CDK-type work for my python app), but please let me know if you do find a proper solution.